# how to use props with filters in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this is my dashboard component that has filters

```
 <a
  @click="interval = 'weekly'"
  >
  Weekly
  </a>
<div><piechart/></div>
<script>
import piechart from "../charts/pieChart.vue";
export default {
   components: {
    piechart
  },
  methods: {
    createPieChart() {
      const weekAgo = new Date(now - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      let allOrders = this.allOrders;
      if (this.interval === "weekly") {
        allOrders = this.allOrders.filter(
          order => new Date(order.created_at) >= weekAgo
        ); 
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

then this is my chart in which i want to filter

```
   <div>
         <div ref="chart"></div>
    </div>
<script>
export default {
   mounted() {
   this.createPieChart();
  },
  methods: {
    createPieChart() {
  }
};
</script>
```

please how can i filter from the dashboard and get the result from pieChart.vue in my dashboard, if i use just the dashboard without another component its works fine ,please how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to the Chart component over a property.
And then use the data from the property in your chart.

Create the `orders` prop.

```
export default {
   props: ['orders'],
   mounted() {
     this.createPieChart();
....
```

Create `allOrders` computed value

```
export default {
   components: {
    piechart
  },
  data() {
    return { interval: null }
  },
  computed: {
       allOrders() {
          const weekAgo = new Date(now - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
          let allOrders = this.allOrders;
          if (this.interval === "weekly") {
             allOrders = this.allOrders.filter(
                order => new Date(order.created_at) >= weekAgo
             ); 
          }
          return allOrders;
       }
  },
  methods: {
  .....
```

and pass `allOrders` to `orders` prop

```
<piechart :orders="allOrders"/>
```